# Unable to get flashdata value on view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

1. I want to get the error message on my profile page regarding image upload.
2. When I trying to upload the large size file then due to CI validations it doesn't upload and redirects to the same profile page but does not shows any error message like "file size is too large".
3. I am using set_flashdata for set the error message but when I tried to print that message to my profile view then it doesn't come on the view.
4. I tried to print all session value on the view but that index is not getting.

**Controller's code -**

```
case 'update_dimg':
/* for updating User Profile image  */

$dUId = isset($_REQUEST['udid']) ? $_REQUEST['udid'] : '';
$bUrl = isset($_REQUEST['bUrl']) ? $_REQUEST['bUrl'] : '';
$ddetails = $this->profile->getDriverDetails($dUId);
$imgPath = isset($_FILES['uDImg']['name']) ? $_FILES['uDImg']['name'] : '';
$this->load->helper('image');
if (!empty($imgPath)) {
    $imageData = do_upload('uDImg', 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', 'driver');

    if (!empty($ddetails->image_path) && !empty($imageData['file_name'])) {
        @unlink('uploads/' . $ddetails->image_path);
        @unlink('uploads/thumbs/' . $ddetails->image_path);
    }
    $imgPath = $imageData['file_name'];
}
$this->data = array('image_path' => $imgPath);
$a = $this->update->driver_basic_info($this->data, $dUId);
if($imageData['error']){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('set_msg', $imageData['errorMsg']);
    $this->session->keep_flashdata('set_msg');
}               
redirect('profile');
die();
break;
```

**View's Code -**

```
<div>
    <?php
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    if($this->session->flashdata('set_msg')){
      echo $this->session->flashdata('set_msg');
    }else{
        echo "else condition";
    } 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You already double checked that you are entering the if and imageData has the message?

Comment: try to call the view direct, the redirect might kill flash data